# Edit app.config values dynamically

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

I want to change a value is my app.config dynamically from my project.

This is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
 <system.web>
   <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
   <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MySqlConnection"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         applicationName="app1" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="6545"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
   </providers>
   </membership>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I want to change the value of 'applicationName' key inside the 'sqlProvider'.

All i could find on the net is people using:

```
 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]
```

But this doesnt work for me.

Comment: Why change it? Can you use applicationName="/" instead ?

Answer (score 0):

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"] usually works with the setting defined under "AppSettings" section. you may try out the following code-

```
public class MembershipSetting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the setting.
    /// </summary>
    public string SettingName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the setting value.
    /// </summary>
    public string SettingValue { get; set; }
}

  private List<MembershipSetting> GetMembershipSetting()
    {
        List<MembershipSetting> settings = new List<MembershipSetting>
                            {
                                new MembershipSetting {SettingName = "Dafult Membership Provider", SettingValue = Membership.Provider.ToString() },
                                new MembershipSetting {SettingName = "Minimum Required Password Length", SettingValue = Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) },
                                new MembershipSetting {SettingName = "Minimum Required Non Alphanumeric Characters",SettingValue = Membership.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)},
                                new MembershipSetting {SettingName = "Password reset enabled", SettingValue = Membership.EnablePasswordReset.ToString()},
                                new MembershipSetting {SettingName = "Maximum Invalid Password Attempts",SettingValue = Membership.MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) },
                                new MembershipSetting {SettingName = "Attempt windows",SettingValue = Membership.PasswordAttemptWindow.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)},
                                new MembershipSetting {SettingName = "applicationName",SettingValue = Membership.ApplicationName.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}
                            };

        return settings;
    }
```

This article is originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18591768).